# C# images, object in use elsewhere error

Tags: c#, multithreading, image

i am extremely new to C# so excuse me if i don't explain this well.

i'm retrieving images from my computer camera, and along with displaying them in a PictureBox, i'm encoding them to jpegs and sending them to a shared dictionary. here's my code:

```
void CurrentCamera_OnImageCaptured(object sender, CameraEventArgs e)
        {
            this.pictureBoxMe.Image = e.Image;

            if (myName != "" && Form1.PicSent)
            {
                SendPic sendP = new SendPic((Image)e.Image.Clone());
                new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(sendP.send)).Start();
            }

        }

 public class SendPic
        {
            Image im;
            public SendPic (Image im)
            {
                this.im = im;
            }
            public void send(){

                Form1.PicSent = false;
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                im.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                var byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();

                Form1.sd["/" + myName + "/video"] = byteArray;

                memoryStream.Close();
                Form1.PicSent = true;

            }
        }
```

the problem is that i'm getting the "Object is currently in use elsewhere." error on the line: SendPic sendP = new SendPic((Image)e.Image.Clone());

based on other forum posts i've found, i already changed it so that the image is passed to the thread, and so that it's a clone. however i'm still getting the same error (though it lasts longer before crashing now).

i read something about locking? how do i implement that in this case? or is there something else i need to do?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It behaves as though the OnImageCaptured method runs on a thread.  Which isn't unlikely for camera interfaces.  Set a breakpoint and use the debugger's Debug + Windows + Threads window to see what thread is running this code.

The failure mode is then that the UI thread is accessing the image to paint the picture box, simultaneously with this worker thread calling Clone().  GDI+ does not permit two threads accessing the same image object at the same time.  It would indeed be flaky, no telling at what exact moment in the time the UI thread starts painting.  PicSent is another accident waiting to happen.

Comment: yes, i think this is a threading problem like you say. how do i fix it? i just tried adding a lock "lock(myLock){}" around both "this.pictureBoxMe.Image = e.Image;" and "SendPic sendP = new SendPic((Image)e.Image.Clone());". however the problem is still occurring. oh, and PicSent was another lame attempt at solving this problem, but it's not working so i'll get rid of it.

Comment: Locking doesn't work, you can't lock the PictureBox' paint code.  Clone the image twice, one for the picture box, another for processing.  I imagine you can skip the second clone.

Comment: Btw, not sure Clone() is good enough.  Use the Bitmap(Image, Size) constructor.

Comment: adding the second clone appears to be working.. it's been running for a couple minutes without crashing. i'll look into Bitmap(..) as well. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that catches my eye is that the `SendPic` class accesses your dictionary asynchronously (the line: `Form1.sd["/" + myName + "/video"] = byteArray;`).

However, dictionaries and hashtables are **not** guaranteed to be thread-safe for write operations. You should be safe if you make the code accessing the dictionary to be thread-safe. A simple `lock` would be a way to start.

Sort of like this:

```
public class SendPic
{
    private object lockobj = new object();
    // .... whatever other code ...

    public void send()
    {
       // .... whatever previous code ...

       lock(lockobj)
       {
          // assuming that the sd dictionary already has the relevant key
          // otherwise you'd need to do a Form1.sd.Add(key, byteArray)
          Form1.sd["/" + myName + "/video"] = byteArray;
       }

       // .... whatever following code ...
    }
}
```

[Quote from MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> **Thread Safety**
>  A Dictionary<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>) can support
>   multiple readers concurrently, as long
>   as the collection is not modified.
>   Even so, enumerating through a
>   collection is intrinsically not a
>   thread-safe procedure. ***In the rare
>   case where an enumeration contends
>   with write accesses, the collection
>   must be locked during the entire
>   enumeration.*** To allow the collection
>   to be accessed by multiple threads for
>   reading and writing, you must
>   implement your own synchronization.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i tried it, but i'm still getting the error in the same spot. also tried adding locks in 2 other spots (see my other comment), but it still doesn't work.